# Open new window in a browser from a PDF

Tags: javascript, url, browser

I have a PDF being presented in a browser, but when you click on a URL it navigates away from the PDF. Is there a way (some Javascript possibly) to make the URL open in a new tab/window instead?

Answer (score 0):

Two options:

- try creating a link with javascript syntax enclosing a new window
  command. See: http://forums.adobe.com/message/3685102#3685102
  Also See: http://forums.adobe.com/message/3685538#3685538
- have a target in your URL.

Answer (score -1):

add target="_top", the _top may be any string.

Sorry! This method only make the pdf file open out of iframe.